# Problems to execute r.in.lidar

Tags: grass-gis, lidar, mac, grass-7.8

I try to open a Lidar file in GRASS GIS 7.8.5 and 7.9 in a Macintosh computer. However, when I try to open the tool  **r.in.lidar**, it appears:
`No such file or directory: 'r.in.lidar'`.

Answer (score 1):

For `r.in.lidar`, you need to have the Liblas library installed (before creating the Mac binary package of GRASS GIS). But Liblas is rather outdated.

As an alternative, you may install [PDAL](https://pdal.io/) and then the addon `r.in.pdal` (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.in.pdal.html) which relies on it.